# How can I do a partial match with Nodejs and MySQL server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

I'm working in an app that has to search content by name, but I need the search function to return all the results that contain the keyword of the search field. For example if I'm looking for a movie which name is "fight club" and I have in my db 10 movies with fight in the name I want to return all the 10 movies and not only the one that can match

My query is something like this:

```
export const querys{
    
 searchContentByName:"SELECT * FROM content where nameContent like '%@nameContent%'",
}
```

But when I do execute that query I found nothing, even when I put all the names that match with the row in db but instead when I define my query like this:

```
export const querys{
    
 searchContentByName:"SELECT * FROM content where nameContent like @nameContent",
}
```

I only get the result that matches exactly with the row in my db.

I've searched and I found that the query for a partial match in mssql server 2019 is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%value%'
```

but I get nothing when structure the query like that in node js

Comment: As to why you're probably not matching any rows, `SELECT * FROM content where nameContent like '%@nameContent%'` is literally looking for rows that contain `@nameContent`, not the value of the `@nameContent` variable, in the `nameContent` column. Have you considered including the `%` characters in your variable? Or maybe rewriting your query to concatenate the `%` characters with the contents of the variable?

Comment: thanks for the advice, i put the % inside the var and it works the solution was:
var nameContent='%'+contentName+'%'